# How can I identify the correct input when I have multiple user-inputs - html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I'm not sure how to frame the question in a sentence which is partly why I'm struggling to find a solution.

I have several input boxes:

```
<td class="inputbox">
<input class="entN" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input">
</td>

<td class="inputbox">
<input class="entN" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input">
</td>

<td class="inputbox">
<input class="entN" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input">
</td>
```

I have a javascript function that reads the input passes it through php and then appends the input to another box connected to each individual input.

```
$(function () {
  $(".entnum").on("click", function () {
    $("#input").focus();
  });

  $("#input").on("keydown", function search(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var input = $(this).val();
      document.cookie = "input = " + input + "; path = /";
      entered = $(this).val();
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajax.open("GET", "input.php", true);
      ajax.send();
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          $("#output1").append(input);

          var element = document.getElementById("output1");

          $("#input").val("");
        }
      };
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass function data for each individual input, e.g. a unique number that I can then use to pass through php, as it is relevant where the input came from, and so I can append the input to the correct unique output box.

Do I just need to use an onclick function so I can send data with the function, or is there a way to do it with what I have so far?

Also what is this type of function called? Window, global?

```
 $(function () {
      $(".entnum").on("click", function () {
        $("#input").focus();
      });
```

Comment: id for each html element is unique(i.e. should be different for all)

Comment: You can use the `name` attribute. Also, each `<input>` should have it's own unique `id`. If you use the js selector `.getElementByID()`, it will only ever get one element

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to have the unique id in the code, but how do I pass the name or call the id in one line of code?